# Trailing Line Decoration Headers in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create header tags with a bit of fancy decoration.

Eventually, I want to arrive at this:

[image: Text Example]

I am having trouble adding the trailing line decoration after the text though.

My original thoughts were to have a container, then in that container would be the h1 and a span tag that would contain the line. But I can't quite seem to get the line to be centered with the text sitting over it.

I tried:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
   display: inline;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

But had no luck. Anyone know any tricks that might help me accomplish this? The main thing is that the length and height of the text is variable, so I am trying to get the line to take up the remainder of the box and sit right in the middle.

I also tried `display: table-cell` with no luck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this

html - `<h2>Test</h2>`

css

```
h2{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
h2:after {
    content:"";
    top:48%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:10px;
    height:5px;
    position:absolute;
    background:orange;
}
```

Comment: Because without overflow:hidden; the width of row will be 100% + width of text. If you repeat word INSIGHT in your jsfiddle 2 times you'll see bottom scroll on result part and maybe understand it. Don't be nervous, this is not your answer, we have written the answers at the same time, I coded this type of headers before and knew the answer - http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/41685.html. Thank you for downvote :) Good luck;)

Answer (score 3):

How about using css pseudo elements like `:after`?

HTML

```
<div class="foo">INSIGHT</div>
```

CSS

```
.foo {
    position: relative;
    color: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.foo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    border-top: 3px solid orange;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/BbYhj/)**

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't require use of 2 separate elements.

Comment: Hmm, looking at this though, the only problem is that the width is fixed. So if I have a longer word I have to adjust the width.

Comment: Yes, this solution is not universal. Add overflow:hidden; on .foo and width:100%; on .foo:after